# Undoing Content Changes Made with Admin Panel

Tags: 6, users

I administer an existing site, and accidentally changed some of the formatting on our homepage.  In the past, I have been able to press "back" on my browser to undo changes, but for some reason it's not working this time.  Does anyone know of a way I can "undo" changes I made to the website under the admin panel?

Comment: i dont think you can "undo", but it will work if you have a DB backup or Git Repo based on your dev env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ability to undo changes depends on what you changed and how your site was set up. Some components of Drupal can be reverted, like if you have revisions enabled on your nodes. A more advanced set-up may have "Features" which allow you to revert all sorts of things. It really depends.

For most changes you make in the admin panel, you need to find the setting you adjusted and change it back to its original value. It would help if you described your issue in more detail, like what settings were being adjusted and what version of Drupal you were using.

Comment: @bryanbruan Thanks for your help!!! I think I accidentally deleted a div container on our front page. There were three boxes lined up in a row, and now the left-most one has no box and is above the others. I am using Drupal 6.

Comment: If your div was in the body of a node and you aren't sure how to correct it, I'd check to see if there are revisions for that node. More information on that here: https://drupal.org/node/320614. If revisions aren't set up, I recommend turning them on for future protection. As for the div, maybe you can compare the html markup for the first box to the other two boxes to see if you can find (and replace) what's missing.